# how to replace \' in python string with '

Tags: python

I'm trying to parse through text scraped from reddit and clean it up for nlp, but the text has backslashes before each single quote. When I try to use string.replace, however there seems to be no effect, with \' staying the same

```
print(submission.selftext.replace('\n','').replace('\\\'','\''))
```

to be clear, there is no issue with replace itself, it removes the end-lines just fine. How do I make replace recognize these characters?

Comment: Using double quotes also makes it easier when dealing with single quotes in strings: print("\\\'".replace("\\'","'")) does actually remove the \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're fine with using regex you can try this -

```
import re
a = "123123\\'\\'213\\'as"
a = re.sub(r'\\(?=\')', '', a)
```

gives `123132''213'as`

Given that you want to only replace the backslashes that are followed by single quotation marks and not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

you can write `chr(92)` to substitute `\`

```
>>> print(chr(92))
\
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#chr

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode code point is
>   the integer i. For example, chr(97) returns the string 'a', while
>   chr(8364) returns the string '€'. This is the inverse of ord().

Comment: I've tried this, to no effect. even trying to replace all backslashes .replace(chr(92),'') doesn't seem to make any difference